# BigQuery LEFT JOIN a table and filter its array elements based on conditions

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery

I want to join a table to another table containing arrays and in the joined result I want to have only the array elements which pass a condition. In this case a date condition. 
The code snippet below illustrates my problem. I want the output to contain only `ids` with `record_dates` less than '2019-10-15'

```sql
WITH platform AS (
        SELECT 'u1' AS id, 'm1' AS platform_id, '2019-10-12' as record_date
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'u2' AS id, 'm1' AS platform_id, '2019-10-13' as record_date
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'u21' AS id, 'm1' AS platform_id, '2019-10-16' as record_date    
), 

platform_agg AS (
        SELECT platform_id
              , ARRAY_AGG(id) as ids
              , ARRAY_AGG(record_date) as record_dates
        FROM platform
        GROUP BY platform_id
),


orders AS(
        SELECT 'u2' AS id, 'c1' AS order_id, '2019-10-15' as order_date 
), 


orders_plus_platform AS ( 
SELECT order_id
      , orders.id 
      , orders.order_date
      , platform.platform_id 
      , CASE WHEN platform.platform_id IS NOT NULL THEN platform_agg.ids ELSE [orders.id] END AS ids
      , CASE WHEN platform.platform_id IS NOT NULL THEN platform_agg.record_dates ELSE NULL END AS record_dates
FROM orders
    LEFT JOIN platform
        ON orders.id = platform.id and platform.record_date <= orders.order_date
    LEFT JOIN platform_agg
        ON platform.platform_id = platform_agg.platform_id 
)

SELECT * FROM orders_plus_platform
```

Below is the current query output, however, in the desired output the `u21` element should be filtered out as the record_date is after '2019-10-15'.

[image]

Thank you,

Comment: ideally you should narrow down your issue and present it in compact and readable way so we can effectively help you. the query you presented has too much noise that most likely has nothing to do with your issue but hides it from us - please consider revisiting / improving your question

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. You are right, the query especially should have been more concise. I have made some edits and I hope the questions is more easy to follow now. Thank you !

Comment: there are still number of ways to reverse engineer your expectations  - instead  - can you explicitly show expected result, so we are not guessing

Answer (score 1):

The below solution worked for me. Basically you join twice to the platform table to get all the ids associated with a platform, instead of joining to a pre-aggregated versions of it. This way you can more easily apply filters.

```
orders_plus_platform AS ( 
SELECT order_id
      , orders.id 
      , orders.order_date
      , platform.platform_id 
      , ARRAY_AGG(CASE WHEN platform.platform_id IS NOT NULL THEN platform2.id ELSE orders.id END) AS ids
      , ARRAY_AGG(CASE WHEN platform.platform_id IS NOT NULL THEN platform2.record_date ELSE NULL END) AS record_dates
FROM orders        
    LEFT JOIN platform
        ON orders.id = platform.id and platform.record_date <= orders.order_date
    LEFT JOIN platform platform2
       ON platform.platform_id = platform2.platform_id AND platform2.record_date <= orders.order_date 
 GROUP BY     
      order_id  
      , orders.id 
      , orders.order_date
      , platform.platform_id 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use subqueries in your `WHERE` clause. Subqueries can run on unnested arrays and return a boolean value - e.g. count of dates < something should be more than zero:

```sql
SELECT c_id
      , c.id 
      , c.c_date
      , cxd.record_id 
      , CASE WHEN cxd.record_id IS NOT NULL THEN rd_agg.ids ELSE [c.id] END AS ids
      , CASE WHEN cxd.record_id IS NOT NULL THEN rd_agg.record_dates ELSE NULL END AS record_dates
FROM c
    LEFT JOIN record_ids cxd
        ON c.id = cxd.id and cxd.record_date <= c.c_date
    LEFT JOIN record_ids_agg rd_agg
        ON cxd.record_id = rd_agg.record_id 
  WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1)>0 FROM UNNEST(record_dates) AS r WHERE r < '2019-10-15')
```